# Git: удаление нескольких веток за один раз?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

Удалить локальную ветку можно при помощи команды

```
git branch -d branch_name
```

Удалить ветку на удаленном git-сервере можно при помощи команды

```
git push origin :branch_name
```

Обе команды удаляют одну ветку. Есть ли способ удалить сразу несколько веток за один раз?

Comment: Допишите их через пробел. И прочитайте наконец документацию

Comment: @AlexeyTen вопрос нормальный, да и практически любой ответ на вопрос можно найти, не используя данный сайт.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вопрос, ответ на который есть в `git branch -h` не показывает попыток разобраться…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

удалить несколько локальных веток:

```
$ git branch -d ветка1 ветка2 ...
Deleted branch ветка1 (was 6bb54a3).
Deleted branch ветка2 (was 6bb54a3).
...
```

удалить несколько веток в репозитории `origin`:

```
$ git push origin :ветка1 :ветка2 ...
To ...
 - [deleted]         ветка1
 - [deleted]         ветка2
...
```